# VTK Toolkit - vtkCutter Performance

Tags: c++, graphics, vtk

I use the VTK Toolkit to load an OBJ file and a vtkCutter to cut through the data set with a play and then draw the outline of the cut. For large objects this is can become quite slow as another user pointed out in the [VTK Users Forum](http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/algorithm-performance-td5722391.html).

Is there a way to make the cutter use a hierarchical data structure to gain better performance?

This is the code:

```
#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkCubeSource.h>
#include <vtkPolyDataMapper.h>
#include <vtkPlane.h>
#include <vtkCutter.h>
#include <vtkProperty.h>
#include <vtkActor.h>
#include <vtkRenderer.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindow.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindowInteractor.h>
#include <vtkOBJReader.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Parse command line arguments
    if (argc != 2) {
        std::cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " Filename(.obj)" << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::string filename = argv[1];
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkOBJReader> obj = vtkSmartPointer<vtkOBJReader>::New();
    obj->SetFileName(filename.c_str());
    obj->Update();

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> mapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
    mapper->SetInputConnection(obj->GetOutputPort());

    // Create a plane to cut,here it cuts in the XZ direction (xz normal=(1,0,0);XY =(0,0,1),YZ =(0,1,0)
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPlane> plane = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPlane>::New();
    plane->SetOrigin(0, 0, 0);
    plane->SetNormal(1, 0, 0);

    // Create cutter
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkCutter> cutter = vtkSmartPointer<vtkCutter>::New();
    cutter->SetCutFunction(plane);
    cutter->SetInputConnection(obj->GetOutputPort());
    cutter->Update();

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> cutterMapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
    cutterMapper->SetInputConnection(cutter->GetOutputPort());

    // Create plane actor
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> planeActor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
    planeActor->GetProperty()->SetColor(1.0, 1, 0);
    planeActor->GetProperty()->SetLineWidth(2);
    planeActor->SetMapper(cutterMapper);

    // Create cube actor
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> cubeActor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
    cubeActor->GetProperty()->SetColor(0.5, 1, 0.5);
    cubeActor->GetProperty()->SetOpacity(0.5);
    cubeActor->SetMapper(mapper);

    // Create renderers and add actors of plane and cube
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> renderer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
    renderer->AddActor(planeActor); //display the rectangle resulting from the cut
    renderer->AddActor(cubeActor); //display the cube

    // Add renderer to renderwindow and render
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> renderWindow = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();
    renderWindow->AddRenderer(renderer);
    renderWindow->SetSize(600, 600);

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> interactor = vtkSmartPointer<
            vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();
    interactor->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow);
    renderer->SetBackground(0, 0, 0);
    renderWindow->Render();

    interactor->Start();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Side note: Though I don't want to be a hater, every time I had to do with this unholy, over-engineered #¼%$@, my conscience yelled: "Stop. Now. Don't use this overly abstracted, deprecated GL, runtime-error prone stuff". Honestly, with the best of intentions: If you can, stop using it, right now. At least, replace the rendering part to create future proof software.

Comment: @Sam What do you suggest he use instead?

Comment: @David Doria : Good question. On shouldn't add comments like the one I did above, without a single clue. I've added some thoughts in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

`vtkCutter` slices meshes using an arbitrarily complex `func(x,y,z)` and is used here with a simple plane to describe that function, which is a common and well covered special case, as the cut countour lies on a simple plane and will hence be a simple (flat) polygon.

- These generic implementations usually cost alot of CPU time, because all special cases of poly cutting are expected to occur in case of `vtkCutter`.
- There's also a slowdown coming from calling virtual functions in the vast class hierarchy of VTK. Without special hacks, it solely depends on the compiler to optimize the virtual function pointer lookup out of a loop, while VTK calls virtual functions (the filter function, for example) many times in one or more nested loops.
  See this for related info: [about the cost of virtual function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292718/about-the-cost-of-virtual-function)
- VTK uses `double`s almost everywhere, even if one could live with `float`s. Conversion and high precision also add quiet a bit of computation and memory overhead.
- VTK (5.8) does not explicitly involve SIMD operations like SSE, afaik.
- ...

Search for topics like these:

- [Algorithm or software for slicing a mesh](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9709970/1175253)
- [Generate 2D cross-section polygon from 3D mesh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797431/generate-2d-cross-section-polygon-from-3d-mesh).

Despite doing this on a CPU, one could also use an OpenGL geometry shader in a transform feedback pass to extract the cut contour determined by a cut plane. Doing this in OpenCL is also possible, however, if no GPU based compute device is available, it might get slower than a C or C++ implementation.

To render the meshes, one could use any OpenGL 3+ capable Renderer:

- [Ogre3D](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=65010)
- [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/)
- [Irrlicht](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/features/)
- [OSG](http://www.openscenegraph.org/)
- a simple, self made OpenGL 3 renderer.
- ...

more: [What is the best way to have realtime 3D rendering in an engineering application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/763408/1175253)